# Clearinterval name isn't defined after JS while loop

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code:

```
var s_wrap = document.getElementById('slider');
var s_list = document.getElementById('slider-list');
var li_items = s_list.getElementsByTagName("li");
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var pos, item_w, refreshIntervalId;

next.onclick = function() { 
    item_w = window.getComputedStyle(li_items[0],null).getPropertyValue("width").split('px')[0]; 
    move('left', li_items[0], 10, item_w);
};

var move = function(direction, el, increment, amount) {
    while(pos <= amount){
        keep_moving = setInterval(function(){
            pos = el.style[direction].split('px')[0];
            if(pos == '') pos = 0;
            pos = parseInt(pos) + increment;
            el.style[direction] = pos + 'px';
        }, 100);
    }
    clearInterval(keep_moving); 

};
```

So basic gist of the code is, click a div, move a div left by 10 pixels at a time until it reaches 600px.

Now am I going about this the wrong way?

At the moment I get a

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: keep_moving is not defined
```

Comment: Is your code running in strict mode? If not, you'd be creating a global variable, which should be accessible.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to declare `var keep_moving` just above the while-loop?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to create multiple intervals in a loop? You're overwriting `keep_moving` in each iteration.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity Oh ok, what you suggest?

Comment: I'd suggest creating  a single interval, and  clearing it when the style has reached its destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetInterval repeatedly does a task. The right way to do it would be

```
function move(direction, el, increment, amount) {
    var pos = parseFloat(el.style[direction]) || 0;
    var repeated = function(){
        el.style[direction] = pos + "px";
        pos += increment;
        if(pos < amount) setTimeout(repeated, 100);
    }
    repeated();
}
```

By the way, the `left` style property moves it to the right (it's how far the element should be from the left)

Comment: I just noticed I made a typo, you might want to look again

Answer (score 1):

```
var move = function(direction, el, increment, amount) {
    var keep_moving; // <=============

    while(pos <= amount){
        keep_moving = setInterval(function(){
            pos = el.style[direction].split('px')[0];
            if(pos == '') pos = 0;
            pos = parseInt(pos) + increment;
            el.style[direction] = pos + 'px';
        }, 100);
    }
    clearInterval(keep_moving); 

};
```

Though I must say the code doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: Would you suggest something better? Just keep moving a div 10px until it's 600px to the left...

Comment: If we discuss about the issue with clearInterval from the question, this answer looks good

Comment: @benhowdle89, the intervals in the loops just seem to be wrong. but this is the way to solve it...

Comment: It looks like Stack Exchange was hacked. Someone wrote an incredibly silly answer for @gdoron with his 19.6k points which seems fishy to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about it the wrong way to answer you.

You are spawning so many intervals and will quickly kill your web page. You should try logic like so:

```
var move = function(direction, el, increment, amount) {
    pos = el.style[direction].split('px')[0];
    if(pos == '') pos = 0;
    pos = parseInt(pos) + increment;
    if(pos > amount) { return; }
    el.style[direction] = pos + 'px';
    window.setTimeout(function() { move(direction, el, increment, amount); },100);
};
```